# pg_stat_activity doesn't update within a procedure or transaction

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I query `pg_stat_activity` but the contents seem to stay the same after the first time I query it within a plpgsql function body, `SERIALIZABLE` or `REPEATABLE READ` transaction.

Why does `pg_stat_activity` not follow the rules for `READ COMMITTED` in a plpgsql procedure?

How do I get the current status? I want to loop over a query against `pg_stat_activity` in plpgsql until another query running on another backend finishes.

Answer (score 16):

PostgreSQL makes a per-backend (per-connection, effectively) cache of the data used by the `pg_stat_get_activity()` function used by both `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_stat_replication`.

This cache is cleared on commit/rollback, but not at the end of each statement within a transaction in `READ COMMITTED` like usual.

You can explicitly clear it with `SELECT pg_stat_clear_snapshot()`. Call it within the body of a PL/PgSQL `LOOP` to refresh.

There is AFAIK no way to ask PostgreSQL to auto-refresh after each statement when using `repeatable read` or higher isolation.

In the source code, see `pgstat_read_current_status(void)` and `pgstat_clear_snapshot(void)`.

Comment: Lifesaver for me. Thanks!