# List transaction timestamps (transaction_timestamp()) of all active (i.e. not yet committed) transactions

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I would like to query for the lowest transaction_timestamp() value among the currently active (not yet committed nor rolled back) transactions from all connections to my PostgreSQL database (I am not interested in just the transaction_timestamp() of my own session).

I can get the transaction xid-s for such by txid_current_snapshot() and related, but I would like to find out what the transaction_timestamp for them are (or at least the lowest of the timestamps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query the `pg_stat_activity` view for that:

```
SELECT MIN(xact_start) FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE state IN ('active', 'idle in transaction')
```

You should have a look at the [possible states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it seems like a good start, but there seems to be something weird going on there. Specifically it always seems to show the state of pg_stat_activity as it was when the transaction of my query reading pg_stat_activity started, and doesn't show new connections opened after my querying transaction, for example. So i.e. I would need to invoke this outside of a transaction.

Comment: And I found this which seems to work around the caching problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421429/pg-stat-activity-doesnt-update-within-a-procedure-or-transaction

Comment: I noticed that the other day. I bypassed the problem by ending the transaction (`autocommit = off`). I didn't know `pg_stat_clear_snapshot()` yet. Thanks for that.